# Printing records from a table but not printing duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, database, inbox

Okay, I wasn't sure how to word it shortly as a question, so sorry it's not worded great. I couldn't find an answer anywhere else (probably down to the fact that I couldn't word my question right)

This is my problem: I have an inbox/outbox system implemented into my website, what I want to do is have a list of names of people who have sent that user a message, but I can't think of any way to do this where it will trawl through the messages table, and only select one record with each username, sorry if that isn't clear enough, happy to expand further if needed..

Comment: Something like SELECT DISTINCT user FROM message.... ? Hard to answer without some code or db schema.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful, if you provided some code & structure of what you have.

I'm assuming you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`sender` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`receiver` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`dateSent` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
`contents` TEXT NOT NULL )
```

and enter data, something like this:

```
id  sender  receiver    dateSent    contents
1   Joe     Jane    4/8/2013 9:15   How are you?
2   Jane    Joe     4/8/2013 9:22   Fine
3   Joe     Jane    4/8/2013 9:27   Can you help me with MySQL?
4   Jane    Joe     4/8/2013 9:31   Sorry. Ask Meg.
5   Joe     Meg     4/8/2013 9:38   Can you help me with MySQL?
8   Meg     Joe     4/8/2013 9:45   Sure!
```

And now you want to know, who sent a message to Joe. Here is SQL:

```
SELECT `sender` FROM `messages`
WHERE `receiver` = "Joe"
GROUP BY `sender`
```

Result of that SQL will be:

```
  Sender
  Jane
  Meg
```

Even though Jane sent Joe 2 messages, her name appears only once.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please upvote or accept it. If not, please comment below, and I will revise and improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best best is to probably create a new table that will represent the 'has sent a message to me (or each other?) before"

You will basically need a many to many relationship table of user id's to represent this.

Create a table HasMessaged, with two columns SenderId and ReceiverId. Then you can join user to itself through this table and for any single user, create a list of everyone who has messaged him. The table would initially need to be populated by running an expensive query once on your messages table but it shouldn't be too bad. Once it is populated you can update it by doing either a simple INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to ensure that the table contains the correct record.